# Mocking DbContext with NSubstitute and Repository is empty or NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, nsubstitute, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to mock my DbContext class to do unit tests with NSubstitute but I cannot recover this data from my fake dbcontext through the repository class.

I have a generic class (SubstituteDbContext) to create sobe DbSet's and set them to the respective DbSet property in my DbContext.

I have the code below for each property in DbContext that I want to mock:

```
var data = DbSetData.MyData();
var dbSet = SubstituteDbContext.DbSet(data);
dbContext.MyObject.Returns(dbSet);
```

I create a DbSet to every property with the method below:

```
public static DbSet<T> getDbSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> data = null)
    where T : class
{
    var dbSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>();

    if (data != null)
    {
        var queryable = data.AsQueryable();
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).Provider.Returns(queryable.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).Expression.Returns(queryable.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).ElementType.Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).AsNoTracking().Returns(queryable);
    }
    return dbSet;
}
```

And in my BaseRepository class (my abstract-parent class for every repository) I have some methods like below to get data:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DbContext.Set<T>()
        .Where(predicate)
        .AsEnumerable();
}
```

But when my debugger runs the List method of BaseRepository I have two possible results (because I tried some variations of the code above):

```
1º I've got System.NotImplementedException
2º The result returned is empty (but
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SUT invokes `DbContext.Set<T>()` however you only set up `dbContext.MyObject.Returns(dbSet)`. You'll need to set up the former.

Answer (score 0):

Like @rgvlee said I wasn't setting up DbSet correctly.

I've changed my `getDbSet<T>` generic method for `setDbSet<T>` because I'm not returning the mocked DbSet anymore and setting it im DbContext in my another generic method with SetValue (from reflection).

Now I'm setting up the generic `Set<T>` property from my mocked DbContext directly in `setDbSet<T>` method and isn't necessary to set it directly with reflection.

Below the code from the new `setDbSet<T>()` (that was `getDbSet<T>()`):

```
public static void setDbSet<T>(DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<T> data = null)
    where T : class
{
    var dbSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>();

    if (data != null)
    {
        var queryable = data.AsQueryable();
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).Provider.Returns(queryable.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).Expression.Returns(queryable.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).ElementType.Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).AsNoTracking().Returns(queryable);
    }

    dbContext.Set<T>().Returns(dbSet);
}
```

And In my generic method that calls `setDbSet<T>()` I've removed the line below where I was setting up that mocked dbSet returned from `getDbSet<T>()` in my DbContext.

`propertyInfo.SetValue(dbContext, dbSet);`

Comment: If you want to persist with mocking the dbcontext, consider using EntityFrameworkCore.Testing (I am the author). It'll automatically take care of all of this setup.